# Since we humans are't able to process any dimensions like 4D and 5D, the distance between stars and galexies appers to be too far away

Tags: gravity, the-sun, dimensions

For exmaple a living oraganism of 2D world is unable to perseive a 3D world.
Similary, do humans have such limitations to perseive the further dimensions that 3D, that could results in wrong understanding size , dimensions of the universe.

The formulas , technology, calcualtions all we have is limited to this 3D world scenarios correct,So that could possible right ?

Comment: This doesn't seem on topic here. Please review https://space.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: In addition to the linked question, please also see here for why extra dimensions are not currently a solution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_extra_dimensions#Empirical_tests